# How to put text and image in a same line?

Tags: html, css

How can I put text and image in a same line, like centered to image?
I tried some method, like vertical-align:middle; display: inline; but not working... where is my mistake?

Now:

[image]

my css code:

```
<style>
    .entryDetailX {
        float: right;
        background: #2B587A;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    .date {
        float: right;
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        background: url(/content/themes/mavi/img/custom/icon_time16x16.png) top left no-repeat;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .nick {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
        color: #cc9900;
        background: url(/content/themes/mavi/img/custom/icon_user16x16.png) top left no-repeat;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="entryDetailX">
    <span class="date">18.01.2011 00:50:55</span>
    <a class="nick">phantasm</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to Add the

```
 background-position:left center;
```

[Check on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae96s/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The images are background images and you need to set their position in the `background` css property. So, instead of `top` you can set `center`.

```
.date {
    background: url(/content/themes/mavi/img/custom/icon_time16x16.png) left center no-repeat;
}
.nick {
    background: url(/content/themes/mavi/img/custom/icon_user16x16.png) left center no-repeat;
}
```

If the above doesn't work, you can set how low the image to be in pixels. So, if you want the images to be 8px lower you can set

```
.date {
    background: url(/content/themes/mavi/img/custom/icon_time16x16.png) left 8px no-repeat;
}
.nick {
    background: url(/content/themes/mavi/img/custom/icon_user16x16.png) left 8px no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property, named `background-position`, to decide the background position. It takes two values, one for horizontal and one for vertical position. It could take `center` for both values.

When you write the following line of code, you set the `background-position` using the shorthand `background`. You explicitly ask to align the background is the top left corner.

```
background: <background-image> <background-position> <background-repeat>;
background: url() top left no-repeat;
```

You should write this code to vertically center your background image:

```
background: url() center left no-repeat;
```

You can play with this property on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/U87n8/).

Cheers,
Thomas.